# Target mobile only javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

So i want my cart to always link when clicked on in header on mobile devices, the script i have works fine on all platforms, but would like to strict it to only mobile. The script is in my blockcart.tpl file(prestashop 1.6.1.9).

```
{literal}
 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(".shopping_cart").click(function() {
     location.href = "{/literal}
     {$link->getPageLink($order_process,true)|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}
     {literal}"; });
 </script>
{/literal}
```

Any help on making this script target mobile only?

i tried this ( but did not work) :

```
{literal}
 {if isset($displayMobile)}
 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(".shopping_cart").click(function() {
     location.href = "{/literal}
     {$link->getPageLink($order_process,true)|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}
     {literal}"; });
 </script>
 {/if} 
{/literal}
```

Comment: "Mobile" is usually a pretty dreadful thing to try to target. What do you *really* care about? Touch screens? Small displays? Metered internet connections? Slow internet connections? Frequently interrupted internet connections? Something else?

Comment: Another way to solve this problem is have:

A. 2 identical buttons. One .shopping_cart_mobile and another .shopping_cart_desktop. 

B. Using media queries, make .shopping_cart_mobile only visible on mobile screens (under a certain size) and .shopping_cart_desktop only visible on screens above the mobile-specified size

C. Have one javascript click event for .shopping_cart_mobile that does your mobile stuff. Have another javascript click event for .shopping_cart_desktop that does your typical landscape stuff.

Comment: i understand i can use display:none; for a certain device width adding another div with link to display int its place for certain screensize , but would really want to use script targeting any mobile device below 736px i would say.. So there is no way of targeting a certain screen size for this to trigger??

Answer (score 0):

There is a PHP class in PrestaShop to detect mobile devices. You can use it to detect mobile devices and pass a smarty variable to check in you blockcart.tpl

```
$mobile = new Mobile_Detect();
if ($mobile->isMobile()) {
            $this->context->smarty->assign('ismobile', 1);
        } else {
            $this->context->smarty->assign('ismobile', 0);
        }
```